# How to set the Before Update property via VBA in Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, subform, beforeupdate

I have a subform that changes its record source (`Form.SourceObject`) based on user input. I am developing a change tracking system that relies on the `Before Update` property of certain fields in the subform (in sheet view if it makes a difference). If I don't change the record source, the `Before Update` will trigger appropriately. If I do change it, it's lost and I need to reassign the trigger. Problem is, I have not been able to find anything describing how this can be done. I have tried using the following where "Tracker" is the code to be called:

```
Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX]![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate = "[Event Procedure]"
```

Error 2455 = "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property BeforeUpdate"

```
Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX]![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate = "Tracker"
```

Error 2455 = "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property BeforeUpdate"

```
Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX]![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate(Tracker)
```

Compile error = Expected Function or variable

```
Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX]![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate  "Tracker"
```

Error 438 = "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Edit-

After playing around with it more, I can assign the `BeforeUpdate` property to controls in the form properly assuming the corresponding before update event is present:

```
Private Sub Assign_Before_Update()
Me.FormCtl.BeforeUpdate = "[Event Procedure]"
End Sub

Private Sub FormCtl_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'Do stuff
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this method still fails with the subform...

I'm starting to think that the fact that I am changing the `Form.SourceObject` is what's blocking me from setting the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to reach controls on a subform, you need to use the .Form property of the subform control.

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]` reaches the main form.

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX]` reaches the *subform control*. The subform control has properties like SourceObject, LinkMasterFields, and LinkChildFields, but doesn't have any controls of its own.

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form` reaches the subform as a true Form object.

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form![Pack Rank]` reaches the control on the subform.

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate` reaches the control's event property.

I'd recommend defining your behavior inside a Function (not a Sub) because then you can call that function directly from a control's event property using the syntax

```
Control.BeforeUpdate = "=MyFunction()"
```

or

```
Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate = "=MyFunction()"
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I can't get the function to work properly. When I try to assign the property it tells me that "The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'MyFunction'. I can't find what that means though...

Comment: Make sure that MyFunction is defined as a Public function (private is default) and that you include the equals sign inside the quotes.

Comment: Still not working, the code I am testing with is below. Do I need to declare something to get it to work?

    Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form![Pack      Rank].BeforeUpdate = "=ToTracking()"

    Public Function ToTracking()
    MsgBox "Success"
    End Function

Comment: Try moving the ToTracking code into a new regular code module, not inside the parent form. Name that new module anything other than ToTracking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this issue - I have made it so that each query that can be selected has it's own subform that is hidden/unhidden as needed. It works, but I don't like the idea of having 5 extra subforms floating around on my main form...